# Redirect using Htaccess- URL has underscore and change it to a slash

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I've gone through a couple dozen answers but none seem to give me what I need, hopefully, someone can help me out here...

My URL structure looks like this

```
https://www.example.com/this-is-static/random_text_32-11
```

and I need to redirect to

```
https://www.example.com/this-is-static/random/text_32-11
```

So it's always the underscore right after "random" that needs to redirect to a slash `/`

Everything after the underscore is dynamic (`random_text_32-11`)

There are other URLs that look like the below and I wouldn't want those affected by this piece of code

```
https://www.example.com/this-is-static/random-words/morerandom/words-change_5-911
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that "random" is intended to be *any random word* (lowercase letters only a-z)? And that "32-11" is also variable?

In which case, try something like the following at the *top* of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(this-is-static/[a-z]+)_([^/]+)$ /$1/$2 [R=302,L]
```

The `$1` backreference matches the first part of the URL-path up to and including the "random" word (excluding the first underscore). The `$2` backreference matches everything *after* the first underscore, excluding any slashes, to the end of the URL-path.

By excluding slashes in the second backreference it naturally fails to match the URL that you don't want to be redirected, since this contains more path segments.

> **UPDATE:** I ran into a slight snag with URLS containing a hyphen right after "this-is-static" ... using the above example, if the word "random" was "random-text" it wont redirect... tried editing the above to no avail

You would just need to add a hyphen to the end of the `[a-z]` character class, ie. `[a-z-]` (the first hyphen represents a *range* `a` *to* `z`). In other words:

```
RewriteRule ^(this-is-static/[a-z-]+)_([^/]+)$ /$1/$2 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you so much! - and you are correct, they were all lowercase as well the "32-11" being variable. ( That's the word I was thinking of, "dynamic" was close but no cigar). I noticed you used R=302, the redirect here is permanent so I changed it to 301 and all is well. Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome. A 302 (temporary) redirect is useful for testing since it's not cached by the browser.

Comment: I see and that makes sense, I ran into a slight snag with URLS containing a hyphen right after "this-is-static"  ...I should have mentioned it but using the above example, if the word "random" was "random-text" it wont redirect... tried editing the above to no avail =(

Comment: You would just need to add a hyphen to the `[a-z]` character class. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you again! Works great. I also appreciate the explanation and your attention to detail.