# Use htaccess to redirect to lower case version of the same URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, centos

Ive looked through other answers and can't seem to get this one right, I've also tried mod_speling but that doesn't seem to fix it

I [have this previous rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62970093/redirect-using-htaccess-url-has-underscore-and-change-it-to-a-slash) that works well and will 301 properly, but then the server will give a 303 to the lower case version ( if there are upper case letters)

So if the url is all lower case its good, if not, it will 301 to the correct url with upper case , then 303 to the final url all lower case. Im trying to get rid of the 303 and make it 301.

Would it be possible to have this rule redirect to a lower case version of the url, or perhaps a new rule is needed?

```
^(this-is-static/[a-zA-Z-]+)_([^/]+)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: See also [How to rewrite URLs from UPPERCASE to lowercase in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64761244/how-to-rewrite-urls-from-uppercase-to-lowercase-in-htaccess) for a "simpler" way to do this on Apache 2.4+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it ENTIRELY in `.htaccess` (not recommended) this should go at the very top of your `.htaccess` file.  At least it should go above ANY other `RewriteRules`. That is because **this uses a loop**, until there are no more uppercase characters to convert, it will keep starting at the first `HASCAPS:TRUE RewriteRule`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If there are caps, set HASCAPS to true and skip next rule
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]

# Skip this entire section if no uppercase letters in requested URL
RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]

# Replace single occurance of CAP with cap, then process next Rule.
RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2
RewriteRule ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ $1c$2
RewriteRule ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ $1d$2
RewriteRule ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ $1e$2
RewriteRule ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ $1f$2
RewriteRule ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ $1g$2
RewriteRule ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ $1h$2
RewriteRule ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ $1i$2
RewriteRule ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ $1j$2
RewriteRule ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ $1k$2
RewriteRule ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ $1l$2
RewriteRule ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ $1m$2
RewriteRule ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ $1n$2
RewriteRule ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ $1o$2
RewriteRule ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ $1p$2
RewriteRule ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2
RewriteRule ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ $1r$2
RewriteRule ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ $1s$2
RewriteRule ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ $1t$2
RewriteRule ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ $1u$2
RewriteRule ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ $1v$2
RewriteRule ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ $1w$2
RewriteRule ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ $1x$2
RewriteRule ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2
RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2

# If there are any uppercase letters, restart at very first RewriteRule in file.
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The better way to do this, but it has to be in the `httpd.conf` file, not `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /${lowercase:$1} [R=301,L]
```

---

Are you sure you are using the `mod_speling` in `httpd.conf` correctly?

```
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
CheckCaseOnly On
CheckSpelling On
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for this but the htaccess code gives a 500 error, when I try the mod speling in ssl.conf ( seems that's how my server is setup) I get this error when I restart apache "  RewriteBase: only valid in per-directory config files"

Comment: Then remove `RewriteBase`.

Comment: Thanks and this worked with a slightly modified version

Comment: What were you modifications?

Comment: I used the rules for .conf from here https://serverfault.com/a/177653/587418