# How to rewrite URLs from UPPERCASE to lowercase in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to assemble a regular expression to rewrite a URL containing uppercase characters to the same URL but in all lowercase.

Example:

`example.com/foO-BAR-bAz` rewrite to `example.com/foo-bar-baz`

`example.com/FOO-BAR-BAZ` rewrite to `example.com/foo-bar-baz`

`example.com/foo-bar-baz` *does not match*

I tried `^\/(?=.*[A-Z])` to match a string with at least one uppercase character but it doesn't match the full string. I also know that I need to use a "capturing group" but I'm not sure how.

I would be implementing this redirect rule in an .htaccess file of an Apache server

Comment: https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-uppercase-lowercase/#Htaccess_Redirect_Uppercase_Lowercase

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/177647/convert-and-redirect-url-in-uppercase-to-lowercase-using-htaccess

Comment: This (specifically, the replacing part) isn’t a thing that should be done in .htaccess. This would be a perfect use case for [RewriteMap](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html#int) using the internal `tolower` function, but that needs access to the server config/virtual host. If that is not an option, then I would rewrite those requests to a tiny little script (PHP, or whatever you have available), that takes part of the lower-casing, and issues an external redirect.

Comment: And a general hint: instead of asking how to do this, have you thought about actually reading a bit about regular expressions? I mean they are 1. really well documented and 2. one of the fundamental things a programmer should know about...

Comment: @CBroe On Apache 2.4 you can use the `tolower()` function in `.htaccess` with an Apache expression in a `RewriteCond` directive. (See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64779809/369434) below.)

Answer (score 6):

If you are on Apache 2.4 then in `.htaccess` you can use mod_rewrite with an *Apache expression* and make use of the `tolower()` function. (This doesn't require the use of a `RewriteMap` in the server config, as mentioned in comments.) For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond expr "tolower(%{REQUEST_URI}) =~ /(.*)/"
RewriteRule [A-Z] %1 [L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* simply checks there is at least one uppercase letter in the requested URL-path. The `RewriteCond` directive then calls the `tolower()` function on the URL-path (`REQUEST_URI` server variable) which is then effectively *captured* using the regex. The `%1` backreference in the *substitution string* then holds the result of the `tolower()` function call, ie. the lowercased URL-path, which is internally rewritten to.

To "correct" the URL and issue an *external redirect*, then just add the `R` flag to the `RewriteRule` directive. For example:

```
:
RewriteRule [A-Z] %1 [R=301,L]
```

---

**UPDATE:** To eliminate a double redirect when redirecting HTTP to HTTPS (and/or non-www vs www) then include the full canonical URL as part of this rule and implement the canonical (scheme + hostname) redirects second.

For example:

```
# 1 - Upper to lowercase conversion (and HTTPS and WWW)
RewriteCond expr "tolower(%{REQUEST_URI}) =~ /(.*)/"
RewriteRule [A-Z] https://www.example.com%1 [R=301,L]

# 2 - HTTP to HTTPS
:
```

Note that the `%1` backreference already includes the slash prefix at the start of the URL-path, so this is omitted in the *substitution* string.

HOWEVER, it is not necessarily incorrect to have a double redirect in this situation. ie. Redirect HTTP to HTTPS (same hostname and URL-path) first then canonicalise other elements of the requested URL (hostname, upper/lowercase URL-path etc.) second. These should be edge cases to begin with, so the real-world impact is minimal.

Note that if you are implementing [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) then it is a requirement that you first redirect from HTTP to HTTPS *on the same hostname*, before canonicalising the hostname (ie. www vs non-www). In this case you should use the `HTTP_HOST` server variable (ie. `%{HTTP_HOST}`) as the hostname in the above redirect. A double redirect cannot be avoided in this scenario.

Comment: @anubhava Thanks. Although I do wonder if there is a "better" method to get the result of the function to the _substitution_ string? Comparing the result to a capturing regex and using the resulting backreference in the substitution, whilst very flexible, feels a bit "hacky" when you just need the entire result?

Comment: @yevg How did you get on with this?

Comment: Here is double redirect. From https:// UPPERCASE_URL / to http:// lowercase_url and after to secure: https:// lowercase_url

Comment: @theblackpost If you are seeing a redirect from HTTPS to HTTP and back to HTTPS then that would seem to be an error with _your_ directives. You can eliminate a double redirect (HTTP to HTTPS _and_ upper to lowercase) by simply including the absolute URL as part of this (upper to lowercase) rule and implement the HTTP to HTTPS redirect second. I've updated my answer.