# Can i use multiple RewriteRules for the same url .htaccess

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, web

My .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^about$ about/about_me.html [L]
```

Is it possible to do this

```
Options -Indexes
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^about$ about/about_me.html [L]

#Using multiple RewriteRules with diffrent names for same url
RewriteRule ^About$ about/about_me.html [L]
RewriteRule ^ABOUT$ about/about_me.html [L]
```

Comment: why you want to do this in the first place? URL's are not case sensitive.

Comment: @tacoshy "not case sensitive"? Then why is there a `NC` flag implemented in the rewriting module?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. You did it, actually. The universe did not implode because of that ;-)

Comment: @arkascha because you can make an url case sensitive if you want to use it for url shortener, base64 or enycrypting. But then only theat specific part will be case-sensitve. By default it is not. SO unless he didnt changed the normal case-insensitve behavior there would be no difference.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the answers i totaly forgot that urls are case senstive, stupid me :):)

Comment: @tacoshy of course URLs are case-sensitive. That several differently "cased" spellings might map to the same file/folder on disk, when the web server runs on a case-insensitive file system, is a different issue, and does not make URLs not case sensitive in themself.

Comment: Sorry, but what you state about case insensivity is simply wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^about$ about/about_me.html [L]
>
> #Using multiple RewriteRules with diffrent names for same url
> RewriteRule ^About$ about/about_me.html [L]
> RewriteRule ^ABOUT$ about/about_me.html [L]
> ```

Yes, you can do this, but... you shouldn't.

`/about` and `/ABOUT` are strictly speaking different URLs. ([URLs *are* case-sensitive.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26196170/369434)) Google sees these as different URLs, so if `/about` and `/ABOUT` both serve the same content then you are potentially creating a duplicate content issue (whether that is actually going to be a problem or not is another matter).

*Aside:* You don't need multiple directives to do this, creating another directive for each variation. You can use the `NC` (`nocase`) flag on the `RewriteRule` directive to make it a case-insensitive match. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^about$ about/about_me.html [NC,L]
```

This will match `about`, `ABOUT` and `AbOuT` etc. and rewrite the request to `about/about_me.html` in all cases.

#### Case-insensitive and avoid duplicate content - Redirect instead

To allow all cased variations of `about` to be accessible and avoid the duplicate content issue you should externally redirect (not "rewrite") the non-canonical variations (eg. `ABOUT` and `AbOuT` etc.) to the canonical `about`. And only rewrite `about` to `about/about_me.html`.

For example, *before* the above "rewrite" you could implement the following "redirect" to canonicalize `ABOUT` and `AbOuT` to `about`.

```
# Redirect "ABOUT" and "AbOuT" to "about"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/about$ [NC]
RewriteRule [A-Z] /about [R=301,L]
```

However, this rule is specific to one URL - it is not very practical if you have more than a handful of URLs. You might instead choose to simply lowercase all requested URLs. For example:

- [How to rewrite URLs from UPPERCASE to lowercase in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64761244/regex-to-rewrite-urls-with-uppercase-characters)