# Redirect using htaccess using a slash, underscore or dates as separators - friendly urls

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This works fine:

```
https://example.com/2023/not-the-dinner-day
```

Using the following `RewiteRule`

```
RewriteRule ^(\d{4})/not-the-dinner-day/?$ archive/reports/$1/ntdd.php [NC,L]
```

I want to get this new URL:

```
https://example.com/2023/not-the-dinner-day-photographs
```

from this old URL

```
https://example.com/archive/galleries/2023/20230204_ntdd/
```

I have tried all sorts of things including:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\d{4})/not-the-dinner-day-photographs/?$ archive/galleries/$1/$2_ntdd/ [NC,L]
```

Matching the last folder `20230204_ntdd` seems to be causing me problems, rewrite module is turned on.

Comment: You have `$2` in the right hand side, but only one set of brackets on the left hand side.  How is the '0204' part to be determined from the original URL?  Will it always be this value?

Comment: If the '0204' part is hardcoded (ie the same for all years), then you could use `RewriteRule ^(\d{4})/not-the-dinner-day-photographs/?$ archive/galleries/$1/$10204_ntdd/ [NC,L]`

Comment: The '0204' changes every year as it is the first Saturday in the month, it could be any four numbers

Comment: So, do you have "0101", "0502", "0503", etc... as well, one for each month? Or is it just one particular month per year?

Comment: I have a year folder followed by a yearmonthday_ntdd folder just for one particular month per year

Comment: mod_rewrite works on transforming URLs.  By default, mod_rewrite doesn't have any functionality for searching the filesystem (although it can test for the existence of files if you know the path already).  If you want to search the filesystem for a matching folder according to some rule, then you could either use `RewriteMap` at the server level (NB can't declare in .htaccess files), or else send the request to some generic helper script (eg written in PHP) where you can implement your folder selection logic

Comment: (Sorry, I got the numbers - months & days - a bit wrong there!) If it's just one month per year then this could be hardcoded. Are you happy to do that? For a limited set of years, this "list" could be hardcoded in `.htaccess`, you wouldn't need to resort to a `RewriteMap` (although that would be desirable if you have access to the server config).

Comment: This almost works RewriteRule ^(\d{4})/not-the-dinner-day-photographs/(\d{4})/?$ archive/galleries/$1/$1$2_ntdd/index.php [NC,L]  gives me https://example.com/2023/not-the-dinner-day-photographs/0204 if I can get rid of the trailing 0204 then I will be done. another rewrite?

Comment: Although that is grabbing a second element from the requested URL that is not present in your example? But otherwise, that should work OK. That rule wouldn't give the output as stated.... that looks like you may have a conflict with another rule? **EDIT:** You can't get rid of the trailing `0204` unless you hardcode this somehow - as mentioned above. (Or rewrite the request to another script.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `0204` (MMDD) part is not present in the requested URL you would need to hardcode code this. Fortunately, there is just one MMDD for any one year.

If you have access to the server config then you could implement a `RewriteMap` that contains the one-to-one mapping - that can then be looked up in `.htaccess`.

Otherwise, you could do something like the following in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond $1-0202 2019-(\d{4}) [OR]
RewriteCond $1-0201 2020-(\d{4}) [OR]
RewriteCond $1-0206 2021-(\d{4}) [OR]
RewriteCond $1-0205 2022-(\d{4}) [OR]
RewriteCond $1-0204 2023-(\d{4})
RewriteRule ^(\d{4})/not-the-dinner-day-photographs/?$ archive/galleries/$1/$1%1_ntdd/index.php [NC,L]
```

The preceding *conditions* contain the one-to-one mapping of YYYY to MMDD. `$1` is the captured 4 digit year from the `RewriteRule` *pattern* and the *CondPattern* then captures the corresponding MMDD from the *TestString*, which is retrieved using the `%1` backreference in the resulting substitution string.

---

*Aside:*

However, there are a couple of potential SEO issues with your original rule:

1. You are allowing an optional trailing slash on the requested URL. But both would return the same resource. These are strictly two different URLs and potentially creates a *duplicate content* issue. If there is a possibility of both URLs (with and without a trailing slash) being received then you should ideally be redirecting from one to the other (whatever is canonical).
2. You are allowing a case-insensitive match. Again, this potentially creates a *duplicate content* issue. If you genuinely have mixed case requests then you should be canonicalising/correcting the request with an external redirect. See the following:
   [How to rewrite URLs from UPPERCASE to lowercase in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64761244/how-to-rewrite-urls-from-uppercase-to-lowercase-in-htaccess)
3. If you are changing an existing URL structure (that has already been indexed and/or linked to by third parties) then you need to implement an external 301 redirect in the other directive, from old to new, in order to preserve SEO.